# How can I pass null values in BETWEEN clause in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I pass null values in BETWEEN clause in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()`.  Or, just break out the logic using `AND` and `OR`:

```
(ap.account_payment_dat >= to_date(#Date From#, 'MM/dd/yyyy') or #Date From# is NULL)  and
(ap.account_payment_dat <= to_date(#Date To#,' MM/dd/yyyy') or #Date To# is NULL
) and
```

Note:  If you are going to be storing date values in the database, then you should use the standard date types, not characters.

Comment: when we make an educated guess off the OP's original statement, I think the two bracketed expressions should be linked with `AND`, so we get a closed interval when both arguments are `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @dlatikay . . . I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported via the `BETWEEN ... AND ...` syntax.

Use something like this instead:

```
WHERE ...
AND (:datefrom IS NULL OR ap.account_payment_dat>=:datefrom)
AND (:dateto IS NULL OR ap.account_payment_dat<=:dateto)
```